# execute SSIS package with config file from another dtsx file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008

Basically I have a DTSX file that, after it finishes executing a few tasks, it reaches an "Execute Package Task" (Or "execute process task if you say so" which calls another DTSX file in the same project. I need to pass in with its call 2 arguments which will define variable values in the DTSX file being called, based on a computation of a previous task. How can i specifiy this in the tool?
basically, the command line looks like this. how do I make it a package task

"E:\LOCATION_OF_DTSX_FILE ARGUMENT1 ARGUMENT2"
OR through a bath file
"LOCATION_OF_BAT_FILE.bat ARGUMENT1 ARGUMENT2"

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling a package from another package, use a parent / child configuration.  Essentially, the parent and child packages have variables that are the same name.  The child package has a parent config (not a config file).  You configure the variables in the execute package task.

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/MikeDavis/ssis/155/passing-variable-values-from-parent-package-to-child-ssis

Alternatively, you can call dtexec with the /set switch which will allow you to set any value in the package that you are calling.  This method is much more cryptic though, I would suggest the former.